# Unable to boot into ElementaryOS on MacBook after PRAM reset

Tags: macos, mac, startup, unix

I installed ElementaryOS on a separate partition of my HDD.

Not sure what happened but the audio in OSX stopped working after the installation. After trying everything else, I found resetting the PRAM resolved the problem.

However, the boot menu no longer shows on startup. The Linux volume won't even show after holding the option key -- only the Mac volume.

I can see the volume in disk utility but it won't mount.

I've tried:

```
sudo bless -mount /Volumes/disk0s5
```

But I get:

```
No mount point for /Volumes/disk0s5
Can't determine mount point of '/Volumes/disk0s5' 
Could not statfs() /Volumes/disk0s5
Could not determine filesystem of /Volumes/disk0s5
```

So, ermm…, I'm stuck.

How do I get my boot options back?

Comment: How did you install ElementaryOS - and why in OSX do you say "The Linux volume won't even show after holding the option key  on ly the Mac volume" if you mean under Liux then the volume is still the Macs

Comment: Elementary was installed on new partition. Boot loader was installed by the installation program. Boot menu hasn't shown since PRAM reset. Holding option key on startup only shows OSX volume not Linux. Volume shows in Disk Utility but won't mount.

Answer (score 1):

Just reinstall rEFInd http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/

This way this runs before Grub which seems to not work very well to boot the Mac OS side of the system